# Remove border around Google Sites Gadget (css)

Tags: css

My apologies in advance, I have VERY modest coding experience.

I'm trying to remove what looks like a three pixel border between a 'mouseover gadget' and an image in Google sites, which is showing in both Chrome and Firefox. I've read about issues with the right use of the border tag -especially with regards to how images show up in chrome- so suspect the bit that goes "body {margin:0; border:0; padding:0;}", but aren't having much luck so far.

Here's the code, thanks in advance for any help!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs 
title="Image Mouseover"
title_url="http://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/image-mouseover"
description="A gadget to create an image mouseover/rollover effect."
screenshot="http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jCm-Pj5NlI8/Tfh722Va6DI/AAAAAAAADzc/DPvpwd7jZYA/s800/image-mouseover_screenshot.png"
thumbnail="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wnq0_4Zc5TE/Tfh72sPAf0I/AAAAAAAADzY/B5do0hJnAEY/s800/image-mouseover_thumbnail.png"
width="400"
height="300">
</ModulePrefs>
<UserPref name="originalImage" display_name="Original image" required="true" />
<UserPref name="rolloverImage" display_name="Rollover image" required="true" />
<UserPref name="text" display_name="Title / tooltip" />
<UserPref name="url" display_name="When clicked, go to URL" />
<UserPref name="target" display_name="Where to open the link" default_value="_parent" datatype="enum">
<EnumValue value="_parent" display_value="Same tab / window" />
<EnumValue value="_blank" display_value="New tab / window" />
</UserPref>
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:0; border:0; padding:0;}
a, span {display:inline-block; background-image:url(__UP_rolloverImage__);}
a:hover img, span:hover img {visibility:hidden;}
</style>
<div id="container"></div><script type="text/javascript">
var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
var url = prefs.getString("url");
var target = prefs.getString("target");
var text = prefs.getString("text");
var originalImage = prefs.getString("originalImage");
var imgTag = '<img src="' + originalImage + '">';
var content;
if (url) {
content = '<a href="' + url + '" target="' + target + '" title="' + text + '">' + imgTag + '<\/a>';
}
else {
content = '<span title="' + text + '">' + imgTag + '<\/span>';
}
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = content;
</script>]]></Content>
</Module>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs 
title="Image Mouseover"
title_url="http://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/image-mouseover"
description="A gadget to create an image mouseover/rollover effect."
screenshot="http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jCm-Pj5NlI8/Tfh722Va6DI/AAAAAAAADzc/DPvpwd7jZYA/s800/image-mouseover_screenshot.png"
thumbnail="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wnq0_4Zc5TE/Tfh72sPAf0I/AAAAAAAADzY/B5do0hJnAEY/s800/image-mouseover_thumbnail.png"
width="400"
height="300">
</ModulePrefs>
<UserPref name="originalImage" display_name="Original image" required="true" />
<UserPref name="rolloverImage" display_name="Rollover image" required="true" />
<UserPref name="text" display_name="Title / tooltip" />
<UserPref name="url" display_name="When clicked, go to URL" />
<UserPref name="target" display_name="Where to open the link" default_value="_parent" datatype="enum">
<EnumValue value="_parent" display_value="Same tab / window" />
<EnumValue value="_blank" display_value="New tab / window" />
</UserPref>
<Content type="html"><![CDATA]><!--here you did not close-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:0; border:0; padding:0;}
a, span {display:inline-block; background-image:url(__UP_rolloverImage__);}
a:hover img, span:hover img {visibility:hidden;}
</style>
<div id="container"></div><script type="text/javascript">
var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
var url = prefs.getString("url");
var target = prefs.getString("target");
var text = prefs.getString("text");
var originalImage = prefs.getString("originalImage");
var imgTag = '<img src="' + originalImage + '">';
var content;
if (url) {
content = '<a href="' + url + '" target="' + target + '" title="' + text + '">' + imgTag + '<\/a>';
}
else {
content = '<span title="' + text + '">' + imgTag + '<\/span>';
}
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = content;
</script></Content><!--here was the closing brackets-->
</Module>
```

Comment: If this is actually an answer, you'll need to provide an explanation as to what you did. Not just dump code and hope everyone understands.

Comment: @j08691 i was just writing in the code where he was wrong and then i did want to comment

Comment: <![CDATA[ you did not close this one  the closing brackets was in the end of the code! you just misst it

Comment: Unfortunately, after changing that as suggested, Gsites reports "The gadget you added is not valid".